# jQuery : How To Get src Value of Multiple img

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this PHP script to generate thumbnails of a directory. number of files inside that directory are dynamic :

```
<?
    if (isset ($product_imgfiles)) {
        echo '<div class="row">';

        for ($i=2; $i<($num_product_imgfiles+2); $i++) {
            echo '<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2" style="padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px;">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail product_imgfiles">
                        <img src="'. $directory . $product_imgfiles[$i] .'" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> hapus</span>
                    </a>
                </div>';
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

and I also have this jquery to listen the event each time the thumbnail is clicked :

```
echo '
$( ".product_imgfiles" ).each( function(index)  {
    $( ".product_imgfiles" ).click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var img_files = $( ".product_imgfiles img" ).attr( "src" );
        alert( img_files );
        alert( \''.$product_token.'\' );
        alert( '.$secret_token.' );
    });
}); 

';
```

the jquery part is able to show alert message. but, unfortunately, the loop won't stop until number of `product_imgfiles` and it shows same `src` value of `img` tag.

while what I need is to get `src` value of `img` tag once the class `product_imgfiles` is clicked. how to get each `src` value of each `img` class when it's clicked? thank you.

Comment: Whoa, whoa... You realise you're attaching the same event handler to *all* `.product_imgfiles` once for every single `.product_imgfiles`? Remove that `.each()` bit!

Comment: Once that's fixed, you'll want to use `$(this)` to refer to the thumbnail that was clicked on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the .each loop.

.click() inherently applies it to each element already, you don't need to loop over them again.

```
echo '
    $( ".product_imgfiles" ).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var img_files = $( this ).children('img').attr( "src" );
        alert( img_files );
        alert( \''.$product_token.'\' );
        alert( '.$secret_token.' );
    });
';
```

Additionally, you need to actually pass the `event` variable into the constructor.
As was brought out in the comments, you reference the current object being clicked with `this` instead of using the selector again.

Also, that confusing bit with the product token and secret token is a little strange. It's going to be the same for every .product_imgfiles object. Is that what you want? If so, that's good! If not, you should store those values as an attribute for each img element in PHP (e.g. `data-product_token='$product_token'`) and then refer to them in JS with something like `$(this).attr('data-product_token')` or `$(this).data('product_token')`.

Comment: This only fixes a background issue, not the problem at hand.

Comment: hi bro, thanks for your reply. but I got `undefined` value of `img_files`. is it because the `src` value belongs to `img` tag, while `.product_imgfiles` class is attached to `<a >` tag? I tried to move `.product_imgfiles` into `img` but doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even notice that. You can use jQuery's built-in children() function to get the element that are the immediate children of the current element. I've updated my answer, see if that helps your needs.